# as3 textfield changing string value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am new in as3 in flash. i need to show an alert. in alert box the shown text field is like : "ou ra ro la atio hata". But the real text that i want to show is like "Mouse drag drop play action hata".

at the code pair the text field is like "Mouse drag drop play action hata". and when i debug code, also i see the text field like same. actually i did not find out why the text field is changing like "ou ra ro la atio hata". is it changing, or replacing, or removing etc. i really don't know.

when i copy the text in alert box which is like "ou ra ro la atio hata", then paste it to the notepad, the text is shown like original text which is like "Mouse drag drop play action hata".

is there anyone to help me ???

thanksss

Comment: Please add some meaningful code. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the few details mentioned in your questions, I think this is a problem of text appearance of your dynamic text field which is in a direct relationship with embedding fonts in your Flash project. To avoid such behavior, you can take a look on these links :

- [Adobe Help : Embed fonts for consistent text appearance](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/embed-fonts-consistent-text-appearance.html).
- [Google Help : Embed fonts for a dynamic text field](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/2661568?hl=en).
- [Adobe Help : Embed fonts in flash](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/how-to/embed-fonts-in-flash.html)  (video tutorial).
- [Adobe Flash Developer Center : Embedding fonts](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts.html) (old article for CS4).

Hope that can help you.