# XML letters missing in my flash web gallery

Tags: html, xml, flash, flash-cs6

I am busy building a website for personal use. In my website I mostly use flash and I have a gallery that is using flash. My gallery gets its images from a XML document. My problem is that in my xml document if I for example use the following sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <photos>
<photo filename="5.jpg" thumbnail="5-thumb.jpg" description="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" />
</photos>
```

The description is fine in the document but on my flash gallery, 11 of the 26 alphabet letters doesn't show. the missing letters are (B,F,J,M,Q,U,V,W,X,Y,Z).

Am I getting my syntax wrong or what?

Comment: Looks fine to me, possibly an issue with your HTML?

Comment: @KyleT, I doubt it because the only data in the html is embedding the .swf and .fla documents. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think it's a problem of embedding font for dynamic text field, take a look on [my answer for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940167/as3-textfield-changing-string-value/27942874#27942874), it was the same problem.

Comment: @akmozo, thank you will have a look