# Why doesn't my app show the random number?

Tags: actionscript-3, math

I am working on a math app using adobe flash cs6 and actionscript 3.0. But when I try to run it in the emulator, the number doesn't show. Also, I am unable to type number 3,6,7,8,9 in the input area.

This is the actionscript that I used in my app, please help me.

```
    var m:int=1+Math.floor(10*Math.random())
    var n:int=1+Math.floor(10*Math.random())
    angka1.text=String(m);
    angka2.text=String(n);

    periksa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ceksoal)

    function ceksoal(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var p:int=Number(jawaban.text)
        if (m+n==p){
            hasil.text="Benar";
        }else{
            hasil.text="salah";
        }
    }

    ulang.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buatsoal)

    function buatsoal(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        m=1+Math.floor(10*Math.random())
        n=1+Math.floor(10*Math.random())
        angka1.text=String(m);
        angka2.text=String(n);
        jawaban.text="";
        hasil.text="";
    }
```

Comment: I think that your problem is because you are not embedding your font, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27942874/2256820).

Comment: thank you, i keep trying. and i found that i can type the number after change in the embed menu