# Flash Professional Arabic TextAria support

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

how can I add TextAria with Arabic support
i.e.

```
dir="rtl"
align="right"
```

Please I need Flash Professional source code, I don't use Flash Builder of Flex systems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you are looking for, you have to start by embedding your font, for that take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27942874/2256820), then you can do like this :

```
// your embedded font
var font:Font = new MyFont();

var text_format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    text_format.font = font.fontName;
    text_format.align = 'right';

var text_area:TextArea = new TextArea();
    text_area.setStyle('textFormat', text_format);
    text_area.width = 300;
    text_area.height = 200; 
    addChild(text_area);
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you very mush... but is there any way to also add dir="rtl"

Comment: @Almoujtahed I think that you are speaking about [Spark TextArea](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextArea.html), in Flex, which use `direction = "rtl"`.

Comment: Exactly but not in Flash Professional, is there any way to enable dir=rtl in Flash Pro,

I found it extremely strange that Adobe didn't offer such functionality.

Thanx Again