# Access full XML attribute text in ActionScript 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I've got an XML file that has the structure below:

```
<page>
      <layer>
        <label value="tenant a1">
          <input description="tenant1" name="tenant1" type="string" displayName="tentant1 name" />
        </label>
        <label value="xx01">
          <input description="location1" name="location1" type="string" displayName="tentant1 location" />
        </label>
      </layer>
      <layer>
        <label value="tenant a2">
          <input description="tenant2" name="tenant2" type="string" displayName="tentant2 name" />
        </label>
        <label value="location a2">
          <input description="location2" name="location2" type="string" displayName="tentant2 location" />
        </label>
      </layer>
</page>
```

I'm looping over the `<layer>`s with this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < xml.page.layer.length(); i++) { 
    names.push((xml.page.layer[i].label[0].attribute('value') + '\n'));
    numbers.push((xml.page.layer[i].label[1].attribute('value') + '\n'));
}
```

When I `trace()` the items, I get the expected "tenant a1". When I actually set the text property of a dynamic text box on my stage, I get "tenant a" without the number at the end. How can I get the full value of the XML attribute to display in my stage?

Comment: I think it's just an embedding fonts problem, for that, take a look on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27942874/2256820) of this question.

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [akmozo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2256820/akmozo) for the hint, this was an issue with font embedding. Because the Flash file that I was editing had a font embedded in it, it was causing issues with my dynamic text box. I removed the font (it was unused), and my text started displaying correctly.