# ActionScript 3 Could not display numbers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am a beginner for ActionScript 3. I use Flash Pro CC.
My problem is the textfield just could not display some characters, such as j, q, z, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9. 
Additionally, after I run the .swf file, I even could not input these characters in input text (eg. the text of input textfield will be not changed after input "j"), but other characters could be inputted. 
I am sure that my keyboard is no problem :), could someone help me ?

Comment: It's clearly a problem of embedding fonts, take a look on [my answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27942874/2256820), it can help.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the font of that textfield, now it is ok.