# My if-statement doesn't work

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, if-statement

It's either going to be "Riktig, bokstaven forekommer" for right letter chosen or otherwise. What have i done wrong, when i start it now none of the Messages show.

```
btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);

var feil:Array = new Array  ;

var riktig:Array = new Array  ;

var bokstav:Array = new Array  ;
bokstav[0] = "b";

bokstav[1] = "r";

bokstav[2] = "e";

bokstav[3] = "v"
var txtBokstav:TextField = new TextField( );

txtBokstav.maxChars = 1;

txtBokstav.restrict = "a-z æ ø å";

txtBokstav.type = flash.text.TextFieldType.INPUT;

 addChild(txtBokstav);

function start(evt)
{
    var bokstavInn:String = String(txtBokstav.text);

    if (txtBokstav.text.length == 1)
    {
        if (bokstav.indexOf(bokstavInn) >= 0)
        {
            txtUtskrift.text = "Riktig, bokstaven forekommer";

            riktig.push(bokstavInn);

            for (var i = 0; i < riktig.length; i++)
            {
                txtUtskrift.appendText(riktig[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txtUtskrift.text = "Feil, bokstaven forekommer ikke";

            feil.push(bokstavInn);

            for (var l = 0; l < feil.length; l++)
            {
                txtUtskrift.appendText(feil[l] + ", ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: About your question, to verify if your `if` statement is working or not (or any other instruction in reality), you can use a simple `trace()` to show some text because when using a `TextField` object, you can get an [embedding font](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27942874/2256820) problem for example ... BTW, as you are new in Stackoverflow, try to answer the questions of other members when they are asking you something about your questions, comment their answers, select the correct answer to your question, don't ask a question and get away !

Comment: It's not going to be shown in the Output Panel but rather inside a Box. I'm not very good but isn't it only for the output panel?

Comment: I know, but we use `trace()` to verify if the code is working properly ...

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you sure that `txtUtskrift` is on the Stage and visible?

2) Make sure that `start()` is being called (use a breakpoint or trace)

3) As askmozo suggests, place trace statements in the possible flow of execution.  So, at the beginning of the `start` function, and within each possible `if` condition.  You might add an `else` for the text.length test:

```
function start( evt )
{
    trace( "start()..." );

    if (txtBokstav.text.length == 1)
    {
        // ... what you already have
    }
    else
    {
        trace( "txtBokstav length not valid:", txtBokStav.text.length );
    }

    trace( "...start()" );
}
```