# Actionscript 3: Text not displaying properly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to display numbers in a text field in Flash CS6 but keep coming across this problem. When I run the program either a 0 is displayed or nothing at all.

Here is the code I am using

```
var seconds:Number = 10;

timer_txt.text = seconds.toString();
```

If the value of 'seconds' contains a '0' only the 0 will be displayed and if the value is anything else nothing is displayed. The text field is empty before the program starts.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's an embedding font problem, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27942874/2256820) ...

Comment: the worst part is that Flash is probably telling you to embed the font in the output panel ...

Comment: @BotMaster oops! It was telling me that although I didn't realise what it meant at the time :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [as3 textfield changing string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940167/as3-textfield-changing-string-value)