# Problems with adding Score in text field for AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

New here and learning flash AS3. I am having a problem with a game I'm working on. I am a teacher and it is a review game. I would like to display the score as part of a text field. At the very beginning I declare the variable:

```
var wrongScore:Number = 0;
var correctScore:Number = 0;
```

Then when an object is dragged and dropped I am trying to display an updated score. It is displaying "Number Correct:" and "Number Wrong:" but not giving the value of `correctScore` or `wrongScore`.

```
function left1Drop (e:MouseEvent): void {
   if (left1.hitTestObject(leftTarget))
   {
     left1.stopDrag();
     correct.play();
     correctScore += 1;
     correctScoreText.text= "Number Correct:" + String(correctScore);

     left1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, left1Drag);
   }

   if (left1.hitTestObject(rightTarget))
   {
     left1.stopDrag();
     left1.x = left1StartX;
     left1.y = left1StartY;
     wrong.play();
     wrongScore += 1;
     wrongScoreText.text = "Number Wrong:" + String (wrongScore);
   }
   else
   {
      left1.stopDrag();
   }
}
```

I am guessing my problem is somewhere in the code below. But I believe I am typing it exactly as I've seen it elsewhere.

```
correctScoreText.text= "Number Correct:" + String(correctScore);
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!!!

Comment: could you try correctScore.toString() and wrongScore.toString() instead of String(arg)? I don't see anything wrong with your code. Maybe it's something not shown here. Then again I just got off a labor heavy sunday of scrubbing cars after only 3 hours of sleep and just about to eat so i may be missing something for those reasons XP

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working either... 

I added a trace (correctScore) and trace (wrongScore) and I'm getting the appropriate readout (increasing for every correct and wrong response).

Comment: The only things I didn't include in the script are some other declared variables and the code below //left1 being repeated for each of the other targets.

Comment: @EconSkrill I think it's an embedding font problem, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27942874/2256820) ...

Comment: Well embedding the fonts didn't help but changing my font to one of the standards fixed the problem. Thank you!!!