# AS3 - Numbers won't display in dynamic text field

Tags: actionscript-3

I am writing a program that my brother needs for a project he is working on. It "solves" a password and then shows the number of loops the program goes through before figuring out the solution. I've gotten everything working but the program won't show the numbers in the dynamic text field. It only shows the letters.

Here's the code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, solvePassword);

function solvePassword(e:MouseEvent):void
{
var pass:Number = Number(inputText.text);
var attempts:Number = 0;
var i:String = pass.toString();
var passLength:Number = i.length;
var n:Number = 0;

while(n != pass)
{
    if(passLength == 1)
    {
        n += 1;
        attempts += 1;
    }
    if(passLength == 2)
    {
        n += 1;
        if(n < 10) { n = 10 }
        attempts += 1;
    }
    if(passLength == 3)
    {
        n+=1;
        if(n < 100) { n = 100 }
        attempts += 1;
    }
    if(passLength == 4)
    {
        n+=1;
        if(n< 1000) { n = 1000 }
        attempts += 1;
    }
    if(passLength == 5)
    {
        n+=1;
        if(n < 10000) { n = 10000 }
        attempts += 1;
    }
    if(passLength == 6)
    {
        n+=1;
        if(n < 100000) { n = 100000 }
        attempts += 1;
    }
    if(passLength == 7)
    {
        n+=1;
        if(n < 1000000) { n = 1000000 }
        attempts += 1;
    }
}

i =  "Attempts: " + String(attempts);

trace(i);

aBox.text = i;
```

Any info would help, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [as3 textfield changing string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940167/as3-textfield-changing-string-value)

Comment: If you are using Flash IDE with a custom font, most likely it's because your textfield don't have the numbers embedded for this font. I don't have Flash here but if you select the textfield on the stage, it's somewhere in its properties (something like "Embedded characters" - make sure the Numbers checkbox is selected there. Also check if the textfield have some restriction rules (you can restrict which characters can be displayed)